# Insert substring in another column csv Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, substring

I have the following format in csv file

```
transaction,count,id,type,subtype,descripcion_d
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  4210030031652691,2,,,,
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  4210030031652691,5,,,,
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  5063030031652691,1,,,,
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  5063012331652691,2,,,,
220402  09290660100100D811  7911  5579100340131388,1,,,,
220525  09290660100100D811  7911  5579125487855558,1,,,,
220525  09290660100100D811  7471  5579112255788869,1,,,,
220525  09290660100100D811  7471  5579134567651389,1,,,,
```

I already drop the columns I do not need I only need "transaction" column, so I have my actual file like this

```
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  4210030031652691
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  4210030031652691
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  5063030031652691
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  5063012331652691
220402  09290660100100D811  7911  5579100340131388
220525  09290660100100D811  7911  5579125487855558
220525  09290660100100D811  7471  5579112255788869
220525  09290660100100D811  7471  5579134567651389
```

What I like do is substring is the first 6 numbers and the last 16 digits if they start with 5579

```html
import csv
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('transactions.csv')
df.head(10)
cadena=df["transaction"]
x="5579"
df["Serial"]=""
df["date"]=""
        
   
for i in cadena:
if x in i:
    pin=i.find(x)
    serie=i[pin:]
    longitud=len(serie)
    if longitud==16:
        df.loc[i,"Serial"]=serie
        df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False, na_rep="")
       
        for i in cadena:
            if int(i[0:2])==22:
                agno=(i[0:2])
                mes=i[2:4]
                dia=i[4:6]
                date="20"+agno+mes+dia
                df.loc[i,"date"]=date
                df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False, na_rep="")
```

When I run this I get the following output

```
Transaction,Serial, Date
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  4210030031652691,
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  4210030031652691,
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  5063030031652691,
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  5063012331652691,
220402  09290660100100D811  7911  5579100340131388, 
220525  09290660100100D811  7911  5579125487855558, 
220525  09290660100100D811  7471  5579112255788869, 
220525  09290660100100D811  7471  5579134567651389, 
,,20220402
,,20220402
,,20220402
,,20220402
,5579100340131388,20220402
,5579125487855558,20220525
,5579112255788869,20220525
,5579134567651389,20220525
```

And I'm looking for the following output:

```
Transaction,Serial, Date
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  4210030031652691,,20220402
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  4210030031652691,,20220402
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  5063030031652691,,20220402
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  5063012331652691,,20220402
220402  09290660100100D811  7911  5579100340131388, 5579100340131388, 20220402
220525  09290660100100D811  7911  5579125487855558, 5579125487855558,20220525
220525  09290660100100D811  7471  5579112255788869, 5579125487855558,20220525
220525  09290660100100D811  7471  5579134567651389, 5579134567651389,20220525
```

Or

```
Transaction,Serial, Date
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  4210030031652691,
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  4210030031652691,
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  5063030031652691,
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  5063012331652691,
220402  09290660100100D811  7911  5579100340131388, 5579100340131388, 20220402
220525  09290660100100D811  7911  5579125487855558, 5579125487855558,20220525
220525  09290660100100D811  7471  5579112255788869, 5579125487855558,20220525
220525  09290660100100D811  7471  5579134567651389, 5579134567651389,20220525
```

I do not know if I'm missing some function to keep in the same row the substring result

Answer (score 0):

You could create separate columns for those substrings and then write them to a CSV file to get the format you want.

```
sim_csv = io.StringIO(
'''220402  09290660100100D811  5711  4210030031652691
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  4210030031652691
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  5063030031652691
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  5063012331652691
220402  09290660100100D811  7911  5579100340131388
220525  09290660100100D811  7911  5579125487855558
220525  09290660100100D811  7471  5579112255788869
220525  09290660100100D811  7471  5579134567651389
''')

df = pd.read_fwf(sim_csv, widths=[999999], header=None, names=['transaction'])
print(df)

                                         transaction
0  220402  09290660100100D811  5711  421003003165...
1  220402  09290660100100D811  5711  421003003165...
2  220402  09290660100100D811  5711  506303003165...
3  220402  09290660100100D811  5711  506301233165...
4  220402  09290660100100D811  7911  557910034013...
5  220525  09290660100100D811  7911  557912548785...
6  220525  09290660100100D811  7471  557911225578...
7  220525  09290660100100D811  7471  557913456765...

df[['date','serial']] = df['transaction'].str.extract(r'^(?P<date>\d{6}).*(?P<serial>\d{16})$')

df['serial'] = df['serial'].where(df['serial'].str.startswith('5579'),'')

print(df[['transaction','serial','date']])
```

**Result**

```
                                         transaction            serial    date
0  220402  09290660100100D811  5711  421003003165...                    220402
1  220402  09290660100100D811  5711  421003003165...                    220402
2  220402  09290660100100D811  5711  506303003165...                    220402
3  220402  09290660100100D811  5711  506301233165...                    220402
4  220402  09290660100100D811  7911  557910034013...  5579100340131388  220402
5  220525  09290660100100D811  7911  557912548785...  5579125487855558  220525
6  220525  09290660100100D811  7471  557911225578...  5579112255788869  220525
7  220525  09290660100100D811  7471  557913456765...  5579134567651389  220525
```

From there you can just save as CSV:

```
df.to_csv('your.csv', index=None)
```

**your.csv**

```
transaction,serial,date
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  4210030031652691,,220402
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  4210030031652691,,220402
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  5063030031652691,,220402
220402  09290660100100D811  5711  5063012331652691,,220402
220402  09290660100100D811  7911  5579100340131388,5579100340131388,220402
220525  09290660100100D811  7911  5579125487855558,5579125487855558,220525
220525  09290660100100D811  7471  5579112255788869,5579112255788869,220525
220525  09290660100100D811  7471  5579134567651389,5579134567651389,220525
```